# check installed Programs if exist do nothing else install programs from list

Tags: powershell

Greeting powershell experts,

```
i have an assignment as class work at school , and i have an idea of a powershell script
```

function is to check if a list of programs are installed on the system or not

powerscript should be started as A self elevating PowerShell script
check>>

if all/some/non

if all are installed >> list installed programs >> print all are installed

if some are installed >> list installed programs + list messing programs >> install the rest with pass command line parameters to Install Custom Actions so that you can enable silent setups  >> print all installed succesfully

if non are installed >> list programs that are going to be installed >>install all from list with pass command line parameters to Install Custom Actions so that you can enable silent setups>> print all installed succesfully

exit powershell

a few more questions:

if i created a list of the programs that i want to install where should i put the list "which folder" and where should i put the *.exe and *.msi files

much apreciated if someone can help me with this

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried and what didn't work. Remember to include some code.

Comment: Homework assignment: Recreate DSC...

Comment: thanks you guys for the quick response , i haven't actually made any script yet . but i did some searching and i found these articles

Comment: A self elevating PowerShell script
'blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2010/09/23/a-self-elevating-powershell-script'

Comment: Use PowerShell to Find Installed Software
'blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/11/15/use-powershell-to-find-installed-software'

Comment: Use PowerShell to Quickly Find Installed Software
'blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/11/13/use-powershell-to-quickly-find-installed-software'

Comment: Get a List of Installed Application from computers (PowerShell)
'gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-a-List-of-Installed-c47393ed'

Comment: so i need a few hints how to start my script i'll much appreciate your help

Comment: Well, it looks like you found information on the code that will do the bits that you need to do so I would say the next step is to open an editor and start typing. The ISE is always an option but personally I prefer Visual Studio Code.